# Difference between minimum-sufficient and necessary in math.

Tags: logic, terminology, fixed-point-theorems

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around this concept for some reason.

Take 3 hypothetical questions:

1. "Find the minimal sufficient conditions on **X** such that **Y** is **Z**"
2. "Find the necessary conditions on **X** such that **Y** is **Z**"
3. "Find the conditions on **X** such that **Y** is **Z**"

What are the differences in what these questions are asking?

To put these hypotheticals in a more concrete setting, we can use the following example related to fixed point iteration:

- **X**: $g(x)$
- **Y**: $x_{n+1}=x_n+f(x)g(x)$
- **Z**: "Is at least Quadratically Convergent"

Comment: All seem the same to me at first glance in *this context*. Do you have a source suggesting they should be different?

Comment: Nothing to say specifically that they are different in this context, if these are all the same, I'm just a bit confused as to why a single question would be posed in so many different ways if there weren't any nuance to the language. For instance, I'm not sure whether just the word "conditions" is too ambiguous to mean either "just sufficient" or "necessary" or "minimally sufficient".